# Detect error in javascript (in code) and act accordingly

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have some `var data` which might have a `data[0].substring(1)[1]` or it might won't (regarding the **.substring()**)

**I can't change the data I receive, neither does it come in a specified format**. Please don't ask about it, the idea of this question is precisely to answer in this scenario.

I tried to do this

```
if(data[0].substring(1)[1]){

}
```

but it fails anyway with `Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined` so now I'm in doubt on how I should do this.

Is this possible? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You need to check if `data[0]` exists (and is a string) first.  `if(typeof data[0] === 'string' && data[0].substring(1)[1])`

Comment: `(1)[1]` weird....Why not just look at that character and not bother with a substring...

Comment: (if `data[0]` exists, and is greater than 1 char long) wouldn't `data[0].substring(1)[1]` be the same as `data[0][2]`?

Comment: `data[0].substring(1)[1]` is the same as `data[0][2] ` @PaulRoub even if it's not more than 1 char long, they'll both return undefined :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` ;(

Comment: Syntax aside, it would be helpful to see an example of `data`. There's a wrong assumption or two here, but we can't see what they might be.

Comment: @AndreCalenta Rocket Hazmat never suggested any assignments. Either you mistyped, or that error is coming from a different line of code.

Comment: AndreCalenta Um, the code that @RocketHazmat posted should not give that error....Did you copy it wrong?

Comment: guys I have an input likewise "2[something:"something",another:"thing"]".

I'm using substring to get rid of the 2 and I'm targeting the second array member `"another: 'thing'"`. data[0] has to do with another array.

Comment: That will not do what you think it will do. It will just give you `s`. You need to parse your string, for that we'd have to know the rules regarding that encoding. But you should try parsing that string on your own first

Comment: That bears *no* relation to your description. Even without the 2, you're left not with an array, but with a string. If that string is trying to be JSON, it's failing - that's array brackets (`[`...`]`) surrounding object contents (`foo:"bar"`)

Comment: @AndreCalenta - please edit your question to put the actual type of string you're getting because now that you've disclosed that in your comments, it changes the ENTIRE question.  Always include sample data for questions like this.  It makes the question a lot clearer.  All prior answers are worthless because you're code was completely wrong for parsing your data string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try/catch/finally`:

```
var txt;
try{
    txt=data[0].substring(1)[1];
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    console.log("The variable does not contain this data."); // at your own choice
}
finally{
    if(txt!=undefined){
    // do stuff with txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid `try/catch` if you can just test it with code. Often, you'll be catching other errors

Comment: The OP's question is not as it seems (when you see what the data is that they're actually trying to parse) so these prior answers are basically rendered invalid.  I deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether `data[0]` exists before trying to access it:

```
if(data[0] && data[0].substring(..)) {
  ...
}
```